# Extract values from an array in codeigniter form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form like this :

```
<input type='text' name='category[]' value='firstcategory'>
<input type='text' name='category[]' value='secondcategory'>
```

and a validation rule like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('category[]', 'Category Name', 'checkcategory');
```

how can I get the values `firstcategory` and `secondcategory` in my `checkcategory` callback?

After I try `print_r($_POST)` it showed me something like :

```
Array ( [category] => Array ( [0] => 'firstcategory' [1] => 'secondcategory' ) )
```

So in order to achieve what I want, I've tried something like this on my `checkcategory` callback :

```
$neddle = array('firstcategory' => $str['category'][0], 'secondcategory' => $str['category'][1]);
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: can you give them different form names - do the validation - and then combine them as necessary? it seems like that would also help if there are validation errors to echo out...

Answer (score 0):

You can't, yet.

There's a feature request for this that will be fulfilled for CodeIgniter 3.1.0: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/193

Comment: Actually, I want to do a validation process with that. In my database, I have an composite unique key, an unique key that built from two fields. I want to return the unique key and grab an array from submitted data by the user and then check if the array submitted by the user is a member of array (composite unique key) returned from database. Could you point me some clues for my problem. I've seen you've been solving so many CI-related questions.

Comment: or in a simple sentence, I want to validate against a composite unique key